# Microsoft Word: Find and Replace Using Wildcards

Tags: replace, ms-word, wildcard

Okay, So I know how to use the wildcard feature of 'Find and Replace' in Microsoft products. What I can't figure out is how to use the wildcards in my replacement text. Below is an example of what I want to accomplish.

I have a 92 page word document. I am trying to add color formatting quickly. The statement 'filling in page # - ITEM # factory or technical' appears 125 times throughout the document. the # after page ranges from 1-5 and the # after ITEM ranges from 1-25 for each page. I did a wildcard look-up to find everything, 'filling in page [0-9] - ITEM [0-9] factory or technical' but what I need to do is change the font color on all 125 occurrences from black to green. I know how to adjust all the formatting, I just don't know how to use the wildcard feature in the 'Replace with' field.

And perhaps this isn't possible. But I have multiple phrases that are similar that reoccur throughout this document and I was hoping to use the 'Find and Replace' feature to speed up this process. An

Comment: Are you using the Find and Replace dialog or VBA code? And are you actually replacing any of the content or simply changing the font colour of the text that is found?

Comment: Using the Find and Replace dialog. Not replacing any content, just the font color of the text that is found. Sorry, I'm bad at explaining things..

Comment: If you're not replacing any content, you can leave the 'Replace With' field empty and just go to the Format options (you have to click inside the 'Replace With' field first) and then Font > Font colour, and pick the colour you want. Or are you looking to change the colour of only certain words in the found text?

Comment: Oh. My. God. I'm stupid. Thank you!!!!